# Getting access to SQL in Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, sql, broadcastreceiver

In a `BroadcastReceiver`, I receive the number of an outgoing call.

I want to compare this phone number with numbers I stored in a SQL database.

Sadly I don't get access in the `BroadcastReceiver` to my database. In other Activitys it works fine.

Here is the code for the `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        //[ getting "string phonenumber" (works)]

        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(context); 
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE_TABLE =" +    potatos, null);

        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Code in `SQLiteAdapter`

```
public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're using the `Context` in the `onReceive(...)` method and NOT `this`.

The reason for this is that `this` isn't a `Context` within a `BroadcastReceiver` and you need one to get access to your database. It works within an `Activity` because an `Activity` is a `Context`

Also, make sure to fix your query which is incorrect and will fail.

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " where " + KEY_CONTENT1 + "=" + phonenumber, null);
```

Where KEY_CONTENT1 is the constant for field inside of MYDATABASE_TABLE for the phone number.

```
SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(context); 
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " where " + KEY_CONTENT1 + "=" + phonenumber, null);
}
```

Comment: I switched it and its still not working :(
Still getting a Nullpointer @ cursor cursor

Comment: You're missing a bit of code to see what is going on. Can you please show your entire `onReceive` or at lease more of what you're doing? You posted the `openToRead()` function, but you don't use that in the code.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm sorry I pasted the wrong piece of code >.< its mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead(); of course!
i edited my original post

Comment: Where do you initialize `sqLiteHelper` at? I believe that is your issue, but don't know where you initialize it.

Comment: I initialize them in extends Broadcastreceiver {
  private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

  private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

 private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
[...]

Comment: I see the variable is declared, but I don't see it being initialized. Is the `openToRead()` function inside your `OutgoingCallReceiver` and that is where it is being done?

Comment: as i said im pretty new :(
no my opentoread is in my sqlliteadapter.java
could you guide me please ? 
Im really sorry for asking such easy questions...

Comment: Could you give me your e-mail ? i could send you all of my code
if its no problem for you ?

Comment: could you just post whats in front of @gmail ?